# Dropdown in nav-pills

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use Tabs in AngularJS. In these Tabs i want to add Dropdownbuttons. For this i use ui-bootstrap. 
AngularJS Version:1.2.27/angular.min.js
Bootstrap Version:ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js

My Code for the tab nav nav-pills:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li ng-repeat="project in projects | orderBy:'column'" ng-class="{ active: isSet(project.column) }">
        <!--<a href ng-click="setTab(project.column)">{{project.name}}</a>   -->
        <!-- Split button -->
        <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setTab(project.column)">
            {{project.name}}
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
            <span class="caret"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Split button!</span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Löschen</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Umbenennen</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="{ active: isSet(0) }">
        <a href ng-click="openNewProjectForm()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

And i always get following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at link (http://localhost:8080/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js:8:24738)
at J (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:54:373)
at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:47:256)
at J (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:54:314)
at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:47:256)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:46:377
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:48:217
at w (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:52:29)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:202:219
at Object.fn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js:109:293) <div class="btn-group" dropdown="">
```

I cant get any informations to solve from the error...

Any ideas?

Comment: you might want to try the development version of the library files(angular js, bootstrap) and then try seeing what errors you get. This will also help you in debugging from within the library code.

Comment: development version is the ucompressed version? i tried the umcompressed but get the same error...